# Does Pressure cook work for hard to soften soybeans?

Tags: boiling, beans, soybeans

I do not have a pressure cook in my house. But the soybean I bought remains really hard after soaking for 24 hours and boiled for 1 hour. I saw someone  saying that some old beans will never soften no matter how long I cook. Is this really true?

One of the poster mentioned 10 min cooking in a pressure cook should soften the beans. This appeals to common sense. But I am still concerned about those people saying "will never soften no matter what".

So, I am asking if any one has tried boiling which did not work but succeeded to soften the beans with pressure cook? I have no need for a pressure cook. And I don't want to buy a pressure cook if it too can not soften stubborn hard soybeans.

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/95711/69382 and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44992/why-wont-my-beans-soften

Comment: and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/93606/cant-get-beans-to-cook-to-tender

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my beans soften?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44992/why-wont-my-beans-soften)

Answer (score 3):

Tried it.  Failed utterly.  If the beans won't soften with overnight soaking and an hour of cooking, you should forget about them.

Answer (score 0):

Soya beans take from 4-6 hours of gentle boiling/ simmering to cook. They're a pain in the ass! They would take maybe 40 minutes in a pressure cooker even. I hate them, but this is the normal cooking time for them.